# How to remove the igw attached to the terraform vpc module for registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

Iam using the vpc module from terraform registry to create vpc.

```html
module "vpc" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version         = "2.77.0"
  ....
}
```

I want to remove the igw attached to the public subnet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Public subnet is defined as one with route to IGW. If you remove IGW, you just create private subnets.

Comment: Yes Iam aware of it, but it is what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module provides `create_igw` [option](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/blob/master/variables.tf):

```
variable "create_igw" {
  description = "Controls if an Internet Gateway is created for public subnets and the related routes that connect them."
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}
```

If you don't want igw, then set it to false:

```
module "vpc" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version         = "2.77.0"
  ....
  create_igw      = false
}
```